# Show that every triangular $3\times3$ matrix $A$ satisfies $(A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2 I)(A-\lambda_3 I)=0$, where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

**My attempt**

Proof. Suppose $A$ is a triangular $3\times3$ matrix. Then so is $A-\lambda_j\operatorname{Id}$ for $1\le j\le3,$ which means that $\det(A-\lambda_j\operatorname{Id})$ is the product of its diagonal entries. Thus $p(\lambda)=\prod(A_{ii}-\lambda),$ and hence the roots of the characteristic polynomial are the diagonal entries $A_{11}$, $A_{22}$, $A_{33}$, as claimed.

I'm not sure whether my approach here is correct. My understanding is that the problem asks us to show that every triangular $3\times3$ matrix $A$ satisfies the determinant formula whereby the lambdas are the roots of the characteristic polynomial and hence eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I think the question should have been to show $(A-\lambda_1I)(A-\lambda_2I)(A-\lambda_3I)=0$ where $\lambda_i=A_{ii}$

Comment: @Shubnam Johri. I couldn't agree more.

Comment: The claim is not that $(A_{11}-\lambda_1 I)(A_{22}-\lambda_2 I)(A_{33}-\lambda_3 I)=0.$ Rather $A-\lambda_i I$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, and the multiplication is matrix multiplication: $(A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2 I)(A-\lambda_3 I)=0. \qquad$

Comment: We haven't covered the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem in class, hence my approach here was to show that every triangular 3-by-3 matrix has eigenvalues equaling its diagonal entries.

Comment: @Michael Hardy. But doesn't every 3-by-3 matrix have its characteristic polynomial equal to the product of the difference between its diagonal entries and $\lambda_i$?

Comment: @Michael Hardy *every 3-by-3 triangular matrix is what I meant.

Comment: It is not particularly tedious to note that the $[A]_{kk}$ are the eigenvalues and just perform the multiplication (you don't need to track every entry).

Comment: @Karam : The problem is still to show that if you multiply three specified matrices, you get the zero matrix, _not_ to show that if you multiply three specified numbers you get the number $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is an upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix, $\lambda_1$,
$\ldots$, $\lambda_n$ its diagonal elements.

Let's show that the matrix
$$\prod_{i=1}^n ( A- \lambda_i I)$$
applied to any vector produces the zero vector. That is enough to see that the matrix is $0$.

The main observation is that $A- \lambda_k I$ applied to a vector with the last $n-k$ components $0$ gets us a vector with the last $n-k+1$ components $0$.

Now, start with any vector $v$. Note that the vector
$$(A- \lambda_n I) v$$ has the last component $0$. Now apply $(A- \lambda_{n-1}I)$ and get
$$(A- \lambda_{n-1}I) ((A- \lambda_{n}I)v$$
with last $2$ components $0$. Continue $n$ steps and get
$$(A- \lambda_1 I) \cdots (A- \lambda_n I) v$$
the vector with all components $0$.

$\bf{Added:}$

In fact we showed that a certain product of matrices with prescribed $0$ positions  is the $0$ matrix. Below is the case $n=3$, $\times$ denotes an arbitrary element:
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \times& \times \\0 & \times & \times \\ 0 &0 &\times \end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left( \begin{matrix} \times & \times& \times \\0 & 0 & \times \\ 0 &0 &\times \end{matrix}\right)\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} \times & \times& \times \\0 & \times & \times \\ 0 &0 &0 \end{matrix}\right) = 0_3$$

as this calculation with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C%20a%2Cb%7D%2C%20%7B0%2Cc%2Cd%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Ce%7D%7D.%7B%7Bp%2C%20q%2Cr%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C0%2Cs%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Ct%7D%7D.%7B%7B%20x%2Cy%2Cz%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%20u%2Cv%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D) shows.

Comment: Explanation: $A$ upper triangular means $A$ invariates a (standard) flag. On the tsuccesive quotients $A$ acts as the multiplications by $\lambda_i$. Hence on the $i$-th quotient $A- \lambda_i I$ is $0$, that is $A-\lambda_i I$ takes $V_i$ to $V_{i-1}$. So the product take $V_n = V$ to $V_0 = 0$.