# Proving Cayley Hamilton theorem in a different way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cayley-hamilton

I'm looking into the proof of Cayley Hamilton theorem from multiple sources. All the proofs I saw use the fact that

$$ (A - \lambda I ) \,\mbox{adj} (A - \lambda I ) = | A - \lambda I | I  $$

The proof is not very hard but a bit involved to my taste. Here is my idea for an alternative proof:

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$. $A$ is similar to its Jordan Normal Form matrix $J$ namely  $ A = P J P^{-1} $  where $P$ is invertible. It is easy to show that if $J$ satisfies Cayley Hamilton then the same is true also for $A$ (I'm skipping the proof for this as it is straight forward).

So we are left to prove that $J$ satisfies Cayley Hamilton, namely if $J$ has $k$ distinct eigenvalues and $\lambda_i $ is an eigenvalue of $J$ with multiplicity of  $m_i$ then

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k} (J - \lambda_i I)^{m_i} = 0$$

The matrix $J$ consists of Jordan blocks, one or more blocks  for each distinct eigenvalue and its eigenvalues are on the main diagonal. Let $B_i$ be the $m_i \times m_i$ Jordan matrix combining all the Jordan blocks corresponding to $\lambda_i$  in $J - \lambda_i I$. The entries of $B_i$ are $0$ except maybe the entries on the superdiagonal which can be either $0$ or $1$( depending on the exact form of $J$). It is not hard to prove that $B_i^{m_i} = 0 $  (I'm skipping this as well).

If we look at the expression $\Pi_{i=1}^{k} (J - \lambda_i I)^{m_i} $, we see that each
$ (J - \lambda_i I)^{m_i} $ term nullifies the sub matrix $B_i$ and the whole expression evaluates to zero as we wanted to prove.

This is just a proof idea. Do you think it is valid ? If yes I wonder why is not used more to prov the Cayley Hamilton theorem ?

Comment: Hmm... Cayley-Hamilton holds over any field, and whether or not the characteristic polynomial splits. What do your sources do, and what do you do, if the characteristic polynomial does not split, and so there is no Jordan canonical form to play with?

Comment: I see - so lets  limit the discussion to the complex field.

Comment: It is not that hard to prove it for an upper triangular matrix, for exp https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142295/show-that-every-triangular-3-times3-matrix-a-satisfies-a-lambda-1-ia-l/4142696#4142696

Comment: Do you think the Jordan normal form is less involved than $A\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)I$ (which is basically just Cramer's rule/Laplace expansion)? Your proof works over fields (by passing to splitting fields), however, the Cayley-Hamilton theorem works also for f.g. modules over commutative rings and I don't see how your proof would generalize to that. That said I think sometimes CH-theorem is proved using a similar idea, namely writing the vector space as $V=k[t]/(p_1)\oplus\dots\oplus k[t]/(p_m)$ and inspecting the annihilator of the sum. The JNF is just a refinement of the right side.

Comment: The method you used is almost exactly the same with the proof of the General Cayley-Hamilton theorem on the book Differential Equations & Linear Algebra (C. Henry, David E., David T.)

Comment: You may wish to check out the wikipedia page on Cayley-Hamilton; it gives both proofs you mention, the one involving the adjoint matrix and the one involving JNF. It gives several other proofs and discusses the relationship between the different proofs.